# Regex that matches Camel and Pascal Case

Tags: regex, parsing, camelcasing, pascalcasing

I'm about to write a parser for a language that's supposed to have strict syntactic rules about naming of types, variables and such. For example all classes *must* be PascalCase, and all variables/parameter names and other identifiers *must* be camelCase.

For example `HTMLParser` is not allowed and must be named `HtmlParser`. Any ideas for a regexp that can match something that is PascalCase, but does not have two capital letters in it?

Comment: I believe that last sentence should be "...but does not have two **consecutive** capital letters in it?"

Comment: Suppose I want to write a C preprocessor in that language.  Must I name my class Cpreprocessor?  Are underscores (C_Preprocessor) allowed?

Comment: Would `H` be a valid class name?

Comment: @Chris yeah, it should not have 2 consecutive capital letters in it. C_preprocessor is not allowed, it'd have to be PreprocessorForC or something similar.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**camelCase:**

```
^[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*$
```

**PascalCase:**

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*$
```

Comment: Neither of the above worked for me for some reason. The following did however (?:[a-z]+|[A-Z]+|^)([a-z]|\d)* (remove the |\d if you don't want numbers included.

Comment: This doesn't capture capitals at the end, e.g. ModeA. It also doesn't allow 2 capital letters in a row (which is generally accepted, e.g. CreateAMode, CreateBMode)

Answer (score 4):

`^[A-Z][a-z]*([A-Z][a-z]*)`

This should work for :

1. MadeEasy
2. WonderFul
3. AndMe

this types of patters.

Answer (score 3):

```
/([A-Z][a-z]+)*[A-Z][a-z]*/
```

But I have to say your naming choice stinks, HTMLParser should be allowed and preferred.

Comment: +1 for a regex and a comment on the naming convention that both look suspiciously similar to what I was going to post, though I would simplify the regex to `/(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)+/` (I don't think the OP is concerned with allowing `AaA` as a class name).

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but figured AaA doesn't have two consecutive uppercase letters. A bigger problem not yet addressed by this scheme is numbers, do they count as upper, lower, neither, or both?

Comment: It's missing some details - like numbers, other than that it seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe the items listed can start with numbers (thought I read it somewhere so take it with a grain of salt) so the best case would be something like Roger Pate's with a few minor modifications (in my opinion)

```
/^([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*[A-Z][a-z0-9]*$/
```

Should be something like, Look for a Capital Letter, then at least one small case or number, or more, as well as it looks like it handles just a capital letter as that seems to be required, but the additional letters are optional.

Good luck

Comment: `/([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*[A-Z][a-z0-9]*/.test("HELLO")` is `true`, it requires `^` and `$`

Answer (score 1):

```
^[A-Z]{1,2}([a-z]+[A-Z]{0,2})*$
```

This allows 2 consecutive capital characters (which is generally accepted, but unluckily PascalCase is not a spec).

Answer (score 0):

Although the original post specifically excluded two consecutive capital (uppercase) letters, I'd like to post the regex for `PascalCase` that will answer many comments raised:

- Allowing two consecutive capital letters
- Allowing digits (but not as the leading character in the string)
- Allowing a string ending with a capital letter or a digit

The regex is `^[A-Z][a-z0-9]*(?:[A-Z][a-z0-9]*)*(?:[A-Z]?)$`

When tested against all strings raised in all comments, the following match as PascalCase:

```
PascalCase
Pascal2Case
PascalCaseA
Pascal2CaseA
ModeA
Mode2A
Mode2A2
Mode2A2A
CreateAMode
CreateBMode
MadeEasy
WonderFul
AndMe
Context
HTMLParser
HtmlParser
H
AaA
HELLO
```

The following do *not* match as PascalCase:

```
camelCase
2PascalCase
```

Answer (score 0):

### Lower Camel Case - no digits allowed

```
    ^[a-z][a-z]*(([A-Z][a-z]+)*[A-Z]?|([a-z]+[A-Z])*|[A-Z])$
```

Test Cases: https://regex101.com/library/4h7A1I

### Lower Camel Case - digits allowed

```
    ^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*[A-Z]?|([a-z0-9]+[A-Z])*|[A-Z])$
```

Test Cases: https://regex101.com/library/8nQras

### Pascal Case - no digits allowed

```
    ^[A-Z](([a-z]+[A-Z]?)*)$
```

Test Cases: https://regex101.com/library/sF2jRZ

### Pascal Case - digits allowed

```
    ^[A-Z](([a-z0-9]+[A-Z]?)*)$
```

Test Cases: https://regex101.com/library/csrkQw

For more details on camel case and pascal case check out this [repo](https://github.com/roubles/casing).